# UserControl size changes after inserting in Form

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a Windows Form class named `UI` which has initially no controls in it. There is a custom UserControl `StartPage` which has size `422, 117`.

When I add `StartPage` in `UI` its size changes

```
UserControl c = new StartPage();
c.Dock = DockStyle.Top;          // Also tried DockStyle.Fill
// Size here: 422, 117

Controls.Add(c);
// Size here: 406, 117
```

What is happening and how do I prevent this behavior? I basically want the `UI` to automatically resize itself to contain `StartPage` without using `AutoSize` property.

Is there any standard way to achieve this behavior?

Comment: The form size changes or the controls does?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should increase your form width, currenctly it is to small - so usercontrol is being resized.
You can do it in runtime like this:

```
UserControl c = new StartPage();
c.Dock = DockStyle.Top; 

Width = c.Width + Width - ClientSize.Width;
Height = c.Height + Height - ClientSize.Height;

Controls.Add(c);
```

Answer (score 3):

It happens because of the font, change the usercontrol font to the parent form font and everything will be load as expected.

Answer (score 2):

Another solution is to change the `AutoScaleMode` to `Inherit` in the usercontrol. This takes care of the scaling issues. By default, it will have the value "Font".

```
AutoScaleMode = Inherit
```